# Make content occupy entire width of screen

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a virtical timeline where the content appears either side of a vertical line. This is what I current have:

[image]

As you can see, all the content blocks appear to the left of the line.

Here you can see that the content spans the width of the screen:

[image]

So when I try to shift the content to the right using `float: right` this is what happens:

[image]

The content starts to overlap each other. How do I make it so the content continues to fill the entire width of the screen so the next block appears below and not inline with the preceding block?

Comment: posting some of your code might make this easier but make the child div inside the div your highlighting have a width of 100% and they should fill the entire screen

Comment: post a screenshot of what the actual result should look like. + add some details of the content div.

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS so we can see why it is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: simply put overflow: auto into the container class and float right into the content class. Something like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>

.content {
    float: right
}
.container {
    overflow: auto
}
```